# ¿Cómo creo una página index para un proyecto de ASP.Net WebForm?

Tags: c#, asp.net, aplicación-web, webforms, iis

Tengo un problema, recientemente hice mi primer proyecto en ASP.Net utilizando webforms, pero este proyecto lo creé empty. La situación es que no sé como configurarlo para que cuando lo suba al IIS, este me cargue una página principal.

Cuando lo intento hacer escribiendo la dirección de la página que quiero abrir, solo me sale un error (eso creo que tienen que ver ya que los archivos web form son .aspx). Si alguien me puede dar guía con este problema se lo agradecería.

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. Tu pregunta necesita más detalles para poder comprender el problema. Puedes leer [mcve] e intenta mejorar la calidad de tu pregunta. Haz clic en [edit] y realiza las modificaciones necesarias. Saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En Web forms la página inicial la debes llamar default.aspx.

Puedes revisar la documentación de Microsoft  en el siguiente link.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/iis/configure-default-document-iis

Comment: Vale ya resolví el problema que me estaba aconteciendo, el problema por el cual no podía ingresar a ninguna parte de la pagina, tenia que ver que no había descargado todos los paquetes del IIS para correr aplicaciones webs hechas en ASP.NET, lo que hice fue bajar todos los paquetes de IIS que son para .Net, y bueno ya con la documentación que me pasaste también me permitió abrir la pagina default.aspx. Aquí hice un video sobre como solucionar el problema: https://youtu.be/B2ZZspwXs7w